# Yandex Карты API 2.0 : карта на весь экран

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

можно ли создать кнопку "развернуть" и  при нажатие развернуть карту на весь экран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fNYU2/

[image: карта]

Если же нужно вывести отдельно кнопку увеличения карты, то поступаем так:

http://jsfiddle.net/fNYU2/1/

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap,
    fullScreen = false;

function init () {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.755768, 37.617671],
        zoom: 10
    });
}

$('#toggler').on('click', function () {
    $('#map').toggleClass('maxMap');
    myMap.container.fitToViewport();
});
```

Comment: @lampa спасибо за ответ, мне подходит первый вариант, но в коде на jsfiddle не вижу где при создание карты добавляется кнопка, в опциях есть только "center" и "zoom"

Comment: @halastoi наверно я имел ввиду, что она стандартно включена. В контролах это параметр fullscreenControl:

  ymaps.ready(function () {
   var myMap = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: ['fullscreenControl']
   });
  });